# Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "portainer/portainer:latest" (must force)

Tags: docker, portainer

I am trying `docker run -t noya` locally. I can't seem to reach the 
http://127.0.0.1:9000/  and I can not log in to portainer.io when entering my password.

Now, I am trying to uninstall portainer (to create a new one with a new password for portainer.io) with the command

```
docker rmi portainer/portainer:latest
```

but I keep getting the error

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "portainer/portainer:latest" (must force) - container 5cffeb45c973 is using its referenced image 10383f5b5720
```

Whereas, when I visualize the containers running with `docker container ls` there is nothing showing meaning there is no containers running.

How can I stop the container `5cffeb45c973` from running in order to remove the `portainer/portainer:lates`t image?

PS: I am a newbie to docker.

EDIT:

I tried to remove container `5cffeb45c973` using `docker container rm 5cffeb45c973`

Then, `docker rmi portainer/portainer:latest`

Same error returned as follows

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "portainer/portainer:latest" (must force) - container 2ee006f771cf is using its referenced image 10383f5b5720
```

Apparently a new container with ID `2ee006f771cf` has been automatically referenced to the portainer image

Answer (score 2):

The reason I wanted to delete the portainer image is because I forgot my initial password to portainer.io
Problem reserved by removing the portainer_data by running:

### remove container running

> docker container rm {container_running_id} --force

### remove volume

> docker volume rm portainer_data

### recreate a new portainer_data volume

> docker volume create portainer_data docker
>
> run -d -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 --name portainer --restart always -v
>   /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data
>   portainer/portainer

Now, when you go to http://localhost:9000/ you will be asked to enter a new password for admin just like the first time